# How to add infinite scroller extension to angularjs.datatable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, datatables

I am trying to implement a grid using the angularjs datatable(http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/gettingStarted).

I want to implement the scroller plugin available with jquery datatables. Is this feature already available or if not, how can I add this feature to the angularjs datatable directive?

Answer (score 0):

It's available, [see the plugin.](https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/withScroller) Easily configurable, just be wary of the jquery.datatables' script version - the scroller seems to break with dev versions.